# docker-compose build image or build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like build custom Dockerfile, but i've this message : 

`--> Starting build app
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service app has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.`

I don't understand why the name is `app`. You can see my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: "3"

services:
  webapp-react:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nodejs
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: webapp/react
    container_name: webapp_react
    user: ${UID}:${GID}
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=build

  webapp-nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: webapp/nginx
    container_name: webapp_nginx
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${SITE_URL}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${SITE_URL}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${MAILER_DEFAUT_SENDER_ADDRESS}
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app/build:/www-data/

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Anyone know where did I make an error ?

Thank you !

Comment: I can't make that YAML file result in that error.

Comment: Don't know why this was flagged as an invalid question. It's perfectly valid. Maybe the reviewers don't understand docker.

Answer (score 44):

In my case, I had renamed the services in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but forgot to do the same in `docker-compose.override.yml` and `docker-compose.vs.release.yml`.

Answer (score 15):

**The below applies everywhere that docker-compose is used. I use visual studio docker tools as reference**

**Quick answer**:

> I would thoroughly look at my `docker-compose.override.yml` files for references of the `defined service` in the error description. Then `delete` it. The error mentions that you have a service that is defined in the `override file` but not on the `base docker-compose file`.

Reproduce the problem with visual studio.

I came across the same issue with my docker-compose.

Visual studio also populates `docker-compose.override.yml` by default. When you append services.

Like @Jorn.Beyers mentioned this can be easily replicated if you are using docker tools for visual studio. Append some services run your docker-compose and afterward start removing services or services from your docker-compose.yml.

**The OP's descriptive error will appear**.

> I am not sure if you clean the solution with visual studio you get rid of this problem.
> It did not work for me.

**What I did and solved the problem?**

What I did was I located the place where `docker-compose` is. I found that there is a `docker-compose.override.yml`. Which still references the service I deleted.

So what I did was locate the service inside my `docker-compose.override.yml`. In the below case I still reference `sth.blog.api`.

```
sth.blog.api:
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
ports:
  - "80"
  - "443"
volumes:
  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Looked similar to the above. After I deleted these lines.
I restarted docker-compose and everything runs.

Note

> Since I use visual studio and its magical auto-gen tools.
> Which I guess is where this error mostly appears and can be intimidating, since especially for ***beginners***, the error description gives you the above error and when clicking on the error takes you to a very strange file and not at the source of the problem.

More info about container tool inside visual studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/?view=vs-2019

Comment: In my case I'd changed the service name in docker-compose.yml but hadn't done the same in docker-compose.override.yml.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue when I was removing some applications from the docker-compose and docker-compose-override file in Visual Studio 2019. Cleaning the solution before running docker-compose again did work for me.

Comment: what does 'cleaning the solution' do? I'd like to do the same manually as I don't have Visual Studio

Comment: @dcorking, I believe cleaning the solution in Visual Studio will run `docker-compose down` and removes all the existing containers and images.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, i added service in `docker-compose.override.yml` file, but forgot to add it into `docker-compose.yml file`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. I did a combination of 2 possible ways of fixing it.

1. I copied the desired code from docker-compose.yml and paste it to docker-compose.override.yml, so that both codes to be the same.
2. Then I have just cleaned the solution and finally I run "docker-compose up".

After that it started generating an image in Docker. I hope this will help to anyone with a similar case.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your docker-compose is running the right version. Example: my docker-compose was on version 2.0.1 but in the documentation the latest one is 1.29.2. So, I had to downgrade to the latest version (lol).

Comment: happened to me, instead of downgrading version 2 has this command:`docker-compse-v1`

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to see this error while using VSCode's DevContainer, just delete your .devcontainer folder and autogenerate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that occurred with you, but once I've faced a problem like that, I've solved this by that way.

goto your $user directory
find .docker
inside .docker directory you find config.json

then delete the portion of credHelpers

```
"credHelpers":{"gcr.io":"gcloud","us.gcr.io":"gcloud","eu.gcr.io":"gcloud","asia.gcr.io":"gcloud","staging-k8s.gcr.io":"gcloud","marketplace.gcr.io":"gcloud"},
```

Then restart docker.
Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to clean and then rebuild the project.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you like you made some changes and didn't rebuild the image.

So yes, clean all but also, 
 - clean docker-compose
 - rebuild docker-compose

Comment: can you give more info? how to run the clean docker-compose?

Answer (score -3):

Try running `docker-compose up --remove-orphans` to remove unused containers that might be lingering around.