# docker-compose is invalid on mac but works on windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Problem**

I have a docker compose file that i'm using on windows 10 and also on mac Big Sur.
both machines are running Docker desktop 4.1.1.  Engine 20.10.8

On the windows machine, i can spin up all the containers no problem and i can launch adminer to connect to the mysql database.
But on my mac, the containers are created and started.  But the minute I try to connect to mysql, the mysql container ends up in a loop where it keeps restarting.  And so of course, adminer cannot reach the mysql host and fails.

When I try to use docker desktop to stop the containers, I see this error message:

> "Cannot remove Docker Compose application.  Reason:  Error invoking
> remote method 'compose-action' Error: Command failed: docker-compose
> --file "docker-compose.yml" --project-name "widgets-wp-docker" --project-directory "/Volumes/Crucial/src/widgetstest" down.  The Compose file is invalid because Service nginx has neither an image nor
> a build context specified.  At least one must be provided".

I found this post:
[docker-compose build image or build context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283952/docker-compose-build-image-or-build-context)

But I don't use / have a docker-compose.override.yml.  I'm still googling to see if I find something that resolves my problem.

**Code**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
 #Set Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:${WORDPRESS_VERSION:-php7.3-fpm}
    container_name: ${WORDPRESS_CONTAINER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    container_name: ${MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    restart: always

  nginx:
    container_name: ${NGINX_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${NGINX_HTTP_PORT1}:${NGINX_HTTP_PORT2}
      - ${NGINX_HTTPS_PORT1}:${NGINX_HTTPS_PORT2}
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args: 
       - NGINX_VERSION=${NGINX_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF_DIR:-./nginx}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_LOG_DIR:-./logs/nginx}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${WORDPRESS_DATA_DIR:-./wordpress}:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - ${ADMINER_HTTP_PORT1}:${ADMINER_HTTP_PORT2}
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG NGINX_VERSION=${NGINX_VERSION}
FROM nginx:$NGINX_VERSION

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install openssl \
  && apt-get -y install vim

RUN mkdir -p /etc/openssl/certs
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/snippets
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/openssl/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/openssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt -subj "/C=CA/ST=CA/L=CA/O=CAAA/OU=CAA/CN=commonname"
```

One (significant) thing thats different btwn my windows and mac machines - on the mac, Docker has been configured to save all data onto an external drive...
In my Dockerfile when I'm creating the nginx image, I don't really "say" where to create it.  Does that matter?

Any other tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

So I added context to the build for nginx and that got rid of the one error that shows up when i try stop the containers.
But the mysql container is still stuck trying to restart
Going to see if I can "tail -f" or watch some of the sql logs on this mysql container.

**EDIT 2**

Bingo!  I found the at least part of the problem:

```
admins-Mac-mini-3:widgetstest admin$ docker logs widgets_mysql
2021-11-08 18:25:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.4+maria~focal started.
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/._aria_log.00000001': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/._aria_log_control': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/._ddl_recovery-backup.log': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/._ib_buffer_pool': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: the error tells you that the nginx container has neither an image nor a build context specified. Looking at the sample file you show above there is no image for nginx, just a 'build.dockerfile' reference. Perhaps there is a difference in the windows and mac docker executables around the supported syntax. If you specify a build context and define the folder rather than refer to the dockerfile directly, syntax might work better on both machines?

Comment: Sorry I just included the Dockerfile I'm using.  Missed that the first time around.  @JohnXF.  And I'm googling to see what "build context" means .  thanks.

Comment: So to me the context means that way of defining the context (i.e. folder/location) for the docker build. As pre below (which I don't think I can format correctly in a comment!)  
<br>backend: 
 <br>   image: backend
  <br>  build:
   <br>    context: ./backend

Comment: @JohnXF please see Edit 1

Comment: So I added user: mysql in the mysql build section of docker-compose and it's fixed.